# Cant match multiple line regex

Tags: regex

So ive been trying to match in regex(editpadpro) and i want to match **POLYLINE,TYPE=0x6,RoadID** ONLY, editpadpro flavor =  Perl, Java, .NET any help is appreciated

```
[POLYLINE]
Type=0x6
Label=Lorong Karyawan 18
EndLevel=1
CountryName=MALAYSIA~[0x1d]MYS
RegionName=PAHANG~[0x1d]PHG
CityName=KUANTAN
Zip=25150
RoadID=1154
RouteParam=2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Data0=(3.77022,103.27289),(3.76988,103.27201)
Nod1=0,283024,0
Nod2=1,282992,0
Numbers1=0,O,55,41,N,-1,-1
[END]
```

so far ive used this `\[POLYLINE]\W+(?:\w+\W+0x6)` that match both polyline and Type=0x6

Comment: so far ive used this \[POLYLINE\]\W+(?:\w+\W+0x6) that match both polyline and Type=0x6

Comment: Just searched on multiline on https://regex101.com/ ,,, `/m `is the flag for multi-line

Comment: yea but apart from this [POLYLINE]\W+(?:\w+\W+0x6) im currently stuck :( just need to find RoadID

Comment: `RoadID=(\d+)/gm` - Does that work for you? https://regex101.com/r/hMV28O/1

Comment: Type and RoadID should come after [POLYLINE] in that order? Type is always before RoadID and they can occur in different positions between the other values? See https://regex101.com/r/r4sn2c/1 using 3 capturing groups

Comment: Can you add the pattern that you have tried in the comments to the question?

Comment: sorry idk how to reply to each one haha, to JGFMK no it doesnt work, second question yes they can occur in different position and thanks ill check the link

Comment: the pattern that ive tried is only [POLYLINE]\W+(?:\w+\W+0x6) and thats it, sorry im still learning

Comment: OK GOT IT THANKSSSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 3 capturing groups starting by capturing `[POLYLINE]`.

For the other 2 capturing groups, you can match all the lines that do not start with Type or RoadID, and then capture the line that does using a negative lookahead.

```
(\[POLYLINE\])(?:\r?\n(?!Type).*)*\r?\n(Type=.+)(?:\r?\n(?!RoadID).*)*\r?\n(RoadID=.+)
```

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r4sn2c/1)

**Explanation**

- `(\[POLYLINE\])` **Group 1** match `[POLYLINE]`
- `(?:\r?\n(?!Type).*)*\r?\n` Repeatedly match all lines that do not start with Type
- `(Type=.+)` **Group 2** Match Type= followed by 1+ times any char
- `(?:\r?\n(?!RoadID).*)*\r?\n` Repeatedly match all lines that do not start with RoadID
- `(RoadID=.+)` **Group 3** match RoadID= followed by 1+ times any char

Comment: hey thanks again, and i want to ask you if i want to match **Type** thats only **Type=0x6**

Comment: You could specify it in the pattern instead of the `.+` like  `(\[POLYLINE\])(?:\r?\n(?!Type).*)*\r?\n(Type=0x6)(?:\r?\n(?!RoadID).*)*\r?\n(RoadID=.+)` https://regex101.com/r/kgZvcM/1

Comment: hey thanks man appreciate it, sorry to bother you again but ive a question, i want to replace(or add) for example roadBlabla=1,0,0,0 under RoadID

Comment: @JohnWeck If you want to keep all the current groups, you can put the matches between also in a group and use the 5 capturing groups in the replacement followed by a newline and the text that you want to add https://regex101.com/r/wM06qQ/1 Or if you only want to add the value, you don't need any group but you can just use the full match in the replacement instead followed by the text that you want to add https://regex101.com/r/CEJmQR/1